# Is Microsoft committed to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm creating a rather large application. I've used LINQ to SQL the past year or two, but since it is being deprecated, I'd like to move on to something else, my options being Entity Framework or NHibernate.

I'd prefer Entity Framework because of it's similarities to LINQ to SQL, but I'm a little hesitant to commit to a Microsoft ORM if they are just going to abandon it in a year or two and create something else.

Comment: we cannot possibly know Microsoft's priorities; suggest you browse what's been written on the topic...

Comment: I haven't seen anything about L2S being abandoned.

Comment: Look, if you're really hesitant because you're worried about MS abandoning EF just switch to NHibernate and move on. No one here can give you a definitive answer on what is going to happen with EF two years from now (not even MS can give you this; strategies shift constantly).

Comment: Meanwhile, open source projects die for various reasons -- the project gets bought out and then deprived of a budget, the project leader turns out to be a murderer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser) -- you name it. This whole industry is seriously erratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt the same way about linq to SQL.  I was right to wait but I was also able to wait at that time.  You never know what a company will do.  Who is to say the market will allow them to continue their current committments?  No one knows.  From my reading on SO the EF is a good thing, and you can use Linq to SQL still also.  If you continue to wait for the perfect thing that no company will abandon you should not develop.  Continue to learn and be broad, specializing where you need to.

Its the same question you could ask about any technology.